# Comment expliquer l'expression : Décidément !

Tags: sens, expressions

En réaction à un message d'un ami dont le français n'est pas la langue natale, j'ai utilisé l'expression :

> Décidément !

Il n'a pas compris ce que cela signifie et me voilà bien en peine de lui expliquer car je ne trouve aucun équivalent anglais ou définition en français dans ce contexte.

Pour illustrer le contexte en question, notre conversation était à-peu-près équivalente à :

> — [...] je me suis rendu compte que j'ai encore fait la même faute.
>   — Décidément !

Comment puis-je expliquer le sens de ce mot lorsqu'il est utilisé... et bien dans ce sens ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une bonne définition dans le présent contexte est celle-ci, fournie par [l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/decidement/).

- Évidemment, qui force l'évidence, qui ne cesse de se répéter à chaque fois comme un implacable constat.

[Le Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9ment) confirme cela en ajoutant deux détails supplémentaires importants.

- Utilisé seul, marque la surprise devant la répétition d’une chose.
  — Décidément !

The best I could suggest as a translation is « What about that! Time after time! ».

Comment: La définition de Wiktionnaire correspond à ce que je voulais exprimer, elle m'a échappé lors de mes recherches. Merci !